# Generate PDF file from HTML code

Tags: php, html, css, pdf, document

I would like to generate a PDF file from a HTML code which contains the stylesheet rules, using PHP.

I am trying to do it using the MPDF library, but when is generated it doesn't look like the HTML page. Most of the elements are not situated in the right position and is like some css rules were not applied.

Does anyone know how can I make it look fine, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can check:

To generate PDF check:
https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf
or
https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy

For word docs:
https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

Answer (score 0):

You can get value from another page using post method also. Your choice.

```
<?php $student_id = $_GET['student_id']; ?>
<?php
include("mpdf/mpdf.php");
$html .= "
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
    background-image: url(\"images/ok.jpg\");

    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-top:10pt;
    margin-top: 100px;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
td { vertical-align: top; 
    border-left: 0.6mm solid #000000;
    border-right: 0.6mm solid #000000;
    align: center;
}

p.student_id{
    padding-left : 140px;
    padding-top  : -27px;
} 

</style>
</head>
<body>
<!--mpdf                                                                          

<p class=\"student_id\">$student_id</p>


<sethtmlpageheader name='myheader' value='on' show-this-page='1' />
<sethtmlpagefooter name='myfooter' value='on' />
mpdf-->


</body>
</html>
";

$mpdf=new mPDF();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');

$mpdf->Output();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own script for `docx` creation in following ways.

```
    <?php     
        header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=document_name.docx");


        echo "<html>";
        echo "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=Windows-1252\">";
    ?>
<body>
    <h1>
        <center>Title of the document</center>
    </h1>

    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
</body>
```